# Extremally disconnected space is normal

Tags: general-topology

> A  Hausdorff topological space is called extremally disconnected if the closure of every open set in it is open.
>
> A Hausdorff  topological space $X$ is a normal space if, given any disjoint closed sets $E$ and $ F$, there are neighbourhoods $U$ of $E$ and $V$ of $F$ that are also disjoint.

Is it true that every extremally disconnected space is a normal space?

Comment: $\pi$-Base gives [this counterexample](https://topology.jdabbs.com/spaces/S000110) for a $T_2$ space which is extremally disconnected but not normal.